# Why @media screen is not working on my web?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Error related with @media query.

My HTML code--

```
<div class="Card">
<div class="FestivalPhoto"><img src="Image/test1.jpg" width="300px" alt="MusicFestivalImage"></div>
<div class="FestivalDetails">Hello World</div>
</div>

<div class="Card">
<div class="FestivalPhoto"><img src="Image/test1.jpg" width="300px" alt="MusicFestivalImage"></div>
<div class="FestivalDetails">Hello World</div>
</div>

<div class="Card">
<div class="FestivalPhoto"><img src="Image/test1.jpg" width="300px" alt="MusicFestivalImage"></div>
<div class="FestivalDetails">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

And this is my css--

```
.Card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  padding: 30px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  }

 .FestivalDetails {
   position: absolute;
   width:auto;
   max-width: 500px;
   height: auto;
   display: block;
   padding: 20px 20px;
   }

 .FestivalPhoto {
   height: 200px;
   width: auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: auto;
   background-size: initial;
  }

  @media(max-width: 700) {

   .Card {
     background: #000;
     border-radius: 2px;
     display: block;
     height: 500px;
     margin: auto;
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
     transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
     padding: 30px auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
    }
```

I am trying the Card div to set "margin: auto;" on mobile but it does not work. I also added  in head tag. Please suggest me. And now I am testing responsive on chrome and firefox developer console. Is there any better ways to test? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@media(max-width: 700)` with `@media screen and (max-width: 700)`

Comment: sorry I forgot you have to put px at the end of width, so max-width: 700px

Answer (score 0):

add this in your head tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

also change @media (max-width: 700) to @media (max-width: 700px)

Answer (score 0):

Media query looks okay,  you can switch to @media screen and (max-width: 680px)

In Chrome , when you inspect element, "Toggle device Toolbar" option is available.
You can see how the application looks on different devices as well as application is responsive or not.`

```css
div.logo-inline-div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px 24px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 12.4%;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  padding: 30px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}

.FestivalDetails {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.FestivalPhoto {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: initial;
}

/*@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {*/
@media (max-width: 700) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  div.logo-inline-div {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
  }

  .Card {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
    padding: 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="EightImages.css" />
    <link rel="images" href="images" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />
            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />
            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="images/sunset1.png" />
            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Card">
      <div class="FestivalPhoto">
        <img src="images/sunset1.png" width="300px" alt="MusicFestivalImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="FestivalDetails">Hello World</div>
    </div>

    <div class="Card">
      <div class="FestivalPhoto">
        <img src="images/sunset1.png" width="300px" alt="MusicFestivalImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="FestivalDetails">Hello World</div>
    </div>

    <div class="Card">
      <div class="FestivalPhoto">
        <img src="images/sunset1.png" width="300px" alt="MusicFestivalImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="FestivalDetails">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`